# What is the Latin word for a crossword puzzle?

Tags: word-request

Crucigramma and cruciverbium are both used by Vicipaedia but I find them unsatisfactory:

- *crucigramma* is a mix between a Latin and a Greek root (AFAIK),
- *cruciverbium* almost looks like a misspelling of *cruciverbum*.

I am looking for a single word using two latin roots (or two Greek roots) or possibly a simple expression. There is no need for it be attested but it would be nice.

Comment: You are probably aware of that, but "crucigrama" is already a Spanish word for crossword puzzles.

Comment: And "cruciverba" is how we call crossword in Italian

Comment: Why are you looking even for a term, let alone a single word using Latin or  Greek roots for a concept which did not exist until centuries after both Greek and Latin ceased to be linguas franca?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin 1. Curiosity 2. Because I want to write about that in Latin

Comment: @Laravel Great and even in English, is it correctly "cross word" or "cross-word" or something else?

Translating modern English into ancient Latin is bound to be a fraught journey, because linguistic development over time matters; now is not the same as then.

If your knowledge of Latin is good enough to accommodate this at all, why are you not able to make the translation yourself… and vice versa?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will argue for reconsidering *cruciverbium*, as I don't think the objection against its ending *-ium* is very strong. Latin used *-ium* as an ending for derived abstract nouns, including various compounds, such as *aequinoctium* from *aequus* and *nox.* Several well-attested classical words end in *-verbium,* such as *adverbium* and *prōverbium.* In Plautus, we even find a compound *vēriverbium.*

I think a more well-founded objection to *cruciverbium* would be that noun-noun compounds in general are not very classical in style, and I am not sure it is semantically natural in Latin for a compound of the noun *crux* and the noun *verbum* to be used with the meaning "words in the form of a cross/words that cross each other".

But to modern readers, the word is obviously a calque of English "crossword", so even if the meaning is weird from a purely Latin perspective, I would find it somewhat excusable. I don't think it will be easy to find a better single-word formation from Latin roots.

Comment: Is *cruciverbium* better than *verbicrucium*? It's not obvious which way it should go.

Comment: I wasn't aware of those examples thank you, I am also interested in your answer to Joonas' question

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta An advantage of a word beginning *cruciverb*- is that we already have the word *cruciverbalist* for someone who constructs or solves crosswords.

Comment: @RosieF That is indeed a notable benefit, but this is the first time I've heard of the word "cruciverbalist". I'm curious how the choice of order compares to other two-noun compounds.

Comment: Cross is functioning a bit like an adjective in that it's describing something about the words, right? That would make me want verbicrucium even though that order isn't exactly strict. I guess a related question would be, is there a word-order convention for compound words?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Or simply *verbicrux*?